# Assigning const array of NULL pointers to array in struct inside array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

My struct looks as follows:

```
struct menu {
    uint8_t type;  
    struct menuentry * parent; 
    struct displaystring * fixtexts[5];  
    // uint8_t ftnum;  
    struct menuentry * children; 
    uint8_t chnum;  
    uint8_t state;  
    uint8_t entry;  
    struct displaystring * selentrystr;  
};
```

I make an array of these structs:

```
struct menu gl_menlist[20];  // all menus
```

Assignment fails here:

```
gl_menlist[0].fixtexts={NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

Errors are:

```
Testdisplayarbstring.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Testdisplayarbstring.ino:209: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
Testdisplayarbstring.ino:209: error: expected `;' before '{' token
```

I realised my IDE is actually using a c++ compiler to build the executable. So I tagged it with C++ while all of my code is C only.
If I add empty braces to fixtexts, outcome is similar.

```
Dis0_10.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Dis0_10.ino:209: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
Dis0_10.ino:209: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
Dis0_10.ino:209: error: expected `;' before '{' token
```

I have no clue at the moment...

Comment: Raw arrays can be *initialized* but not assigned to. Since you have a `struct` consider defining a constructor that initialises the members. Have a look at `std::array` as well.

Comment: @user657267 `std::array` is not in C.

Comment: @BartvanNierop Good thing OP tagged this as C++ then.

Comment: The question is tagged C++. OP is using a C++ compiler and asking a C++ question.

Comment: @user657267: `I realised my IDE is actually using a c++ compiler to build the executable. So I tagged it with C++ while all of my code is C only. If I add empty braces to fixtexts, outcome is similar.`

Comment: using a c++ compiler ... c++ compiler ... c++ ...

Comment: `struct menu gl_menlist[20] = { 0 };`

Comment: Because a wrong tag dictates what the answer or advice should be, regardless of what the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: Nah, no need to fight. I was actually expecting c++ solutions but hoping for c solutions, because I'm reluctant to switch over to c++.

Answer (score 1):

You say this is actually C and not C++..

There are 2 options.

1) memset

```
memset(gl_menlist[0].fixtexts, 0, sizeof(gl_menlist[0].fixtexts));
```

2) Wrap the array in another struct and use compiler generate struct copy:

```
struct displaystring_fixed {
    displaystring * a[5];
};
struct menu {
    uint8_t type;  
    struct menuentry * parent; 
    struct displaystring_fixed fixtexts;  
    // uint8_t ftnum;  
    struct menuentry * children; 
    uint8_t chnum;  
    uint8_t state;  
    uint8_t entry;  
    struct displaystring * selentrystr;  
};  

static const displaystring_fixed displaystring_fixed_init = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

gl_menlist[0].fixtexts = displaystring_fixed_init;
```

In the second case the compiler may generate block move instructions, though usually `memset` is well optimized also.  Also in second case you then have to change all accesses of `displaystring_fixed[i]` to `displaystring_fixed.a[i]`.

Comment: I tried 1). It works fine. I'll stick with that, as it is rather comfortable. But I'll try to initialise as much of the big array as possible at the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: You could just initialize the big structure with memset in one go and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a constructor for `menu`, something like (and use a `nullptr`, not `NULL`):

```
struct menu {
    menu() : fixtexts{nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr} ...
    ...
```

Comment: or equivalently just `menu() : fixtexts()` which is valid in C++98 too

Comment: seems reasonable. But AFAIK I can't call the constructor twice, e.g. to overwrite the content, can I?

Comment: @Ariser no, you're right -- you only construct once.  But then you can *assign* new values to your sub-objects any time after construction

Comment: Ok, assignment seems to work now, except my compiler does not know "nullptr". (avr-gcc)